# How does an Elixir/Phoenix app know its own websocket uri?

Tags: websocket, phoenix-framework

I'm beginning to use web sockets with an Elm frontend and a Elixir/Phoenix backend. The Phoenix server needs to tell the Elm app what uri to connect to. (E.g., `ws://localhost:4000/socket/websocket` in the development environment, but something else in the production environment.)

I was hoping there was something the equivalent of `static_url`, but I can't find it. Is there?

(I know I could hardcode the possibilities, but it seems like Phoenix must already know them.)

Comment: Or you can get the host from the client...
http://stackoverflow.com/a/40482399/649830

Answer (score 1):

One way, via Chris McCord, is to change this line in `YourApp.Endpoint`:

```
socket "/socket", Eecrit.UserSocket
```

... with this:

```
@socket_mount "/socket"
def socket_uri() do
  ws_url = String.replace_leading(url(), "http:", "ws:")
  ws_url <> @socket_mount
end

socket @socket_mount, Eecrit.UserSocket
```

Note that this requires the client to add the transport `/websocket` to the end of the URI.

Answer (score 0):

I really figured there'd be a helper function in `Phoenix.Endpoint` for this, but I didn't find anything.

There's likely a better solution, but my quick-and-dirty response would be to examine the `conn` argument that is passed into any Phoenix controller. It has a bunch of useful fields, like `host` and `port`, and a list of request headers (like `host`, from which you could build the websocket URL.